# What does "warning: current Git remote contains credentials" mean?

Tags: git, github

What does "**warning: current Git remote contains credentials**" mean?

(I think it comes from a "git push" command but I'm not sure – it may be coming from some other git command.)

I *think* it is saying that the "git push" command contains credentials in the URL, which is true (the URL is in a script, like https://$CREDENTIALS@github.com/$USER/$PROJECT.git, and the shell variable $CREDENTIALS contains an email address and password).

Or am I wrong, and it is actually saying that the remote server or repository has mt credentials on it and it's warning me that other people can see them? Or something else entirely?

Comment: That message is specific to `git-lfs`. (See `lfsapi/auth.go`, function `setRequestAuthFromURL`). I think it's indicating that the URL includes a password, but I'll let someone else track it down further.